# Gamepad disconects after a while

Tags: linux, kernel, usb, input, usb-device

I have bought some cheap generic usb gamepad (nubwo nj-25).
When I connect, it works for a while, until resting. And then throw errors.

#### Device info

I am using Linux 6.1.52 (NixOS)
Lenovo ThinkPad T14s Gen 1 AMD

#### dmesg

```
[ 3788.152300] usb 6-2: new low-speed USB device number 42 using xhci_hcd
[ 3788.298823] usb 6-2: New USB device found, idVendor=0079, idProduct=0006, bcdDevice= 1.07
[ 3788.298828] usb 6-2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[ 3788.298829] usb 6-2: Product: USB Joystick
[ 3788.298830] usb 6-2: Manufacturer: Microntek
[ 3788.330720] input: Microntek              USB Joystick           as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:08.1/0000:06:00.4/usb6/6-2/6-2:1.0/0003:0079:0006.0010/input/input39
[ 3788.330981] dragonrise 0003:0079:0006.0010: input,hidraw0: USB HID v1.10 Joystick [Microntek              USB Joystick          ] on usb-0000:06:00.4-2/input0
[ 3788.330997] dragonrise 0003:0079:0006.0010: Force Feedback for DragonRise Inc. game controllers by Richard Walmsley <richwalm@gmail.com>
[ 4171.720905] usb 6-2: reset low-speed USB device number 42 using xhci_hcd
[ 4171.985403] usb 6-2: device descriptor read/64, error -71
[ 4172.361332] usb 6-2: device descriptor read/64, error -71
[ 4172.729841] usb 6-2: reset low-speed USB device number 42 using xhci_hcd
[ 4172.993400] usb 6-2: device descriptor read/64, error -71
[ 4173.369630] usb 6-2: device descriptor read/64, error -71
[ 4173.737344] usb 6-2: reset low-speed USB device number 42 using xhci_hcd
[ 4173.737966] usb 6-2: Device not responding to setup address.
[ 4173.941973] usb 6-2: Device not responding to setup address.
[ 4174.149322] usb 6-2: device not accepting address 42, error -71
[ 4174.409303] usb 6-2: reset low-speed USB device number 42 using xhci_hcd
[ 4174.409740] usb 6-2: Device not responding to setup address.
[ 4174.613966] usb 6-2: Device not responding to setup address.
[ 4174.821319] usb 6-2: device not accepting address 42, error -71
[ 4174.821372] usb 6-2: USB disconnect, device number 42
[ 4174.956550] usb 6-2: new low-speed USB device number 43 using xhci_hcd
[ 4175.078372] usb 6-2: device descriptor read/64, error -71
[ 4175.302360] usb 6-2: device descriptor read/64, error -71
[ 4175.519328] usb 6-2: new low-speed USB device number 44 using xhci_hcd
[ 4175.640575] usb 6-2: device descriptor read/64, error -71
[ 4175.870817] usb 6-2: device descriptor read/64, error -71
[ 4175.973475] usb usb6-port2: attempt power cycle
[ 4176.353793] usb 6-2: new low-speed USB device number 45 using xhci_hcd
[ 4176.354190] usb 6-2: Device not responding to setup address.
[ 4176.558209] usb 6-2: Device not responding to setup address.
[ 4176.765451] usb 6-2: device not accepting address 45, error -71
[ 4176.879665] usb 6-2: new low-speed USB device number 46 using xhci_hcd
[ 4176.880034] usb 6-2: Device not responding to setup address.
[ 4177.086015] usb 6-2: Device not responding to setup address.
[ 4177.293320] usb 6-2: device not accepting address 46, error -71
[ 4177.293386] usb usb6-port2: unable to enumerate USB device
```

#### I have tried

```
options usbcore use_both_schemes=y
options usbcore autosuspend=-1
```

Answer (score 0):

That sounds like an issue with the firmware burned into your gamepad. Or maybe something is wrong with it on a hardware level.

The thing is that the controller doesn't even respond to the very basic "hey, are you there? Who are you?" commands that underly even the most basic USB operation. There's nothing your computer can do when it can't talk to the device.

Your host computer including the Linux running on it can do nothing about that. You need to open a warranty claim.